# Rails 6 remove "data-disable-with" submit button on form_with or make it false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on a simple Rails 6 app. When I add some js calls to a page that creates a model it automatically disables the submit button adding a `data-disable-with="Create ModelName"`.
In Rails < 6 we could do 
`{data: { disable_with: false }}`
How can i prevent the button from being disabled?

Comment: Can you show us the code of your button. According to the documentation `data: { disable_with: false }` should still work https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag

Comment: Looks like using `= form.submit data: { disable_with: false, confirm: "Are you sure?" ,class: "btn btn-primary mb-2"}` works. Notice the missing "," after submit